# Configurar xampp en windows para hacer visible una web en internet

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp, localhost

estoy tratando de hacer visible en internet unas webs en XAMPP en windows con dominios NO-IP. En linux Ubuntu lo hago y no tengo problemas con los archivos de configuración.
Pero con XAMPP en windows no lo consigo. He abierto los puertos del router y modificado los archivos httpd.conf donde puse:

Listen 0.0.0.0:80
ServerName 192.168.1.3:80

Luego en el archivo httpd-xampp.conf agrege estas lineas por que **no existian**:
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#

```
# Close XAMPP security section here
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:security))">
 Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>

# Close XAMPP sites here
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
#Deny from all
#Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Pero nada. Tengo un dominio en NO-IP que tiene el mismo nombre que los virtualhost que cree. En /etc/drivers

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 midominio-no-ip.ddns.net
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

La verdad que en ubuntu tengo ya varios dominios creados y funcionando sin problemas pero nunca lo había intentado en windows.

---

Si estan en la misma red. Cambie la configuración de los puerto y l puse en el 8080. En el httpd.conf puse Listen 8080 y el ServerName puse 192.168.1.3:8080.
Luego cree los virtualHost en httpd-vhost.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *:>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\directorio"
ServerName xxxx.ddns.net
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\directorio">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Luego añadi por que no estaba lo siguiente en httpd-xampp.conf lo siguiente:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 127.0.0.0/8
 ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>



#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Allow from all
ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Y no puedo acceder ni ippublica ni dominio NO-IP que tambien lo redirigi a mi ip publica puerto 8080

Comment: Dices que en ubuntu te funciona pero en windows no, ¿pero las pruebas que has hecho en ubuntu son en la misma red? Lo pregunto por descartar que sea un problema de tu proveedor de servicios de internet.

Comment: Hola Ordago. Si estan en la misma red. Cambie la configuración de los puerto y l puse en el 8080. En el httpd.conf puse Listen 8080 y el ServerName puse 192.168.1.3:8080.